# Do trophy bases really get more trophies than farming base?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm at T.H. 7 and recently switched from a farming base to a trophy base. My farming base had the dark elixir storage in the middle and T.H. outside the main area where it was easily snipable and the trophy base had the T.H. and dark elixir storage in the middle. I've noticed the trophy base is almost all around worse.

With the farming base someone would usually destroy just the T.H. and I'd get an 8 hour shield. With the trophy base someone destroys a bunch, usually gets the town hall and dark elixir storage, get's 2 stars and a bunch of loot. Isn't that clearly worse?

In the end doesn't it come down to with the trophy base a lot more gets lost in 8 hours than farming base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little correction: you get a 12 hour shield when either the TH is destroyed or when you lose with between 40%-90% destruction (16 hours for 90% and up).

I would stay that it is a matter of preference. Some players feel they are better with trophy bases, others, not.

Personally, I don't think trophy bases are worth trying unless you are at TH10 and already maxed out most of your defensive buildings (if not all).

If your goal is to get trophies to get into a higher league (and since you are at TH7) and you have a decent amount of time to make attacks, I would advise using a farming base and try not to keep loot in your village. As a TH9, if I find a farming base with decent loot, I can assure you I would not let this village pass with a simple snipe :) (unless I am in a mood to give 'free' shields).

I cannot say for all the players out there, but my experience is that in Gold Leagues and below, players tend to go in regardless of base if there is decent loot. In Crystal and Master, they tend to snipe and move on instead of going in and shoot for the loot. The reason is that people in this league are often shooting for the achievements and are more concerned about trophies (and getting trophies quickly!) and less about loot, and because there is mostly well upgraded TH9 and TH10.

At the moment (we don't know if supercell is launching TH11 soon), TH10 is the best TH level to use a trophy base and push to the legend league.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a high enough league where people from Crystal and above find you, they will most likely snipe your TH and move on for an easy bonus. I have found this at TH9. But for my TH7/8 villages, I always leave out TH because more than likely a low player will take it out for easy trophies. If you do happen to have alot of loot and a stronger player finds you, yes, you will be wiped out. But most of the time a lower guy gives you a shield first. I have never been able to gain trophies with a 'trophy base.'

p.s. don't hide bombs and teslas near the TH, that just enrages people to crush you ;)